# Has anyone been able to get floodFilling on opencv.js?

Tags: javascript, c++, opencv, compilation

It seems opencv.js does not expose Flood Filling due to a raw rect pointer in its signature.

Based on this [answer](https://answers.opencv.org/question/195457/floodfill-missing-in-opencvjs/) I tried removing floodFilling from the blacklist, white list it and then add on line 3587 of imgproc.hpp

A wrapper signature for floodFilling (copy pasted from the answer):

```
// special overload for js:
CV_EXPORTS_W int floodFill( InputOutputArray image, InputOutputArray mask,
                            Point seedPoint, Scalar newVal) {
    return floodFill(image, mask, seePoint, newVal, 0);
}
```

However this fails with error:

```
opencv/build_js/modules/js/bindings.cpp:1326:16: error: call to 'floodFill' is ambiguous
        return cv::floodFill(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
```

If I fully remove the wrapper, the function becomes available in javascript and I can call it, but an undefined exception is thrown.

I have tried to change the signature of the wrapper to use an additional dummy int, string, float and custom structure, but they all fail to compile.

Has anyone been able to expose floodFilling to JS?

Comment: in case you are interested there is a flooddfill plugin implementation in pure javascript in [FILTER.js](https://github.com/foo123/FILTER.js/blob/master/src/plugins/FloodFill.js) project (I am author)

Comment: How fast does it perform?

Comment: pretty fast, test it,but it is not C code (I am thinking of converting at least some to use asmjs but do not have time right now)